# Not able to get the result of two queries into one from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having two queries. First will return be 10 rows and second query will return me 2 rows. But, when I combine the queries into one, it still returns me only 10 rows.

Here are my queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contentmsg 
WHERE  apmc_id = '5284a327e4b0bc1eaf3d118e' 
       AND commodity_id IS NULL 
       AND lang_id IS NULL 
       AND date < '2014-07-05 09:25' 
       AND date >= '2014-06-13 14:17:22' 
ORDER  BY -date 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

output
two records

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contentmsg 
WHERE  apmc_id = '5284a327e4b0bc1eaf3d118e' 
       AND commodity_id IN ( '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33bc', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b6', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33d9', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca3408',
                             '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33e1', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33ec', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b4' )
       AND lang_id = '51fb5a2ee4b0e18f7f89ecc8' 
       AND date < '2014-07-05 09:25' 
       AND date >= '2014-06-13 14:17:22' 
ORDER  BY date 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

output
10 records..

The only difference between those queries is commodity_id is set to null and lang_id is set to null in the first query..

I've tried with this query where I've added "OR"

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contentmsg 
WHERE  apmc_id = '5284a327e4b0bc1eaf3d118e' 
       AND commodity_id IS NULL 
        OR commodity_id IN ( '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33bc', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b6', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33d9', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca3408',
                             '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33e1', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33ec', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b4' )
           AND lang_id IS NULL 
        OR lang_id = '51fb5a2ee4b0e18f7f89ecc8' 
           AND date < '2014-07-05 09:25' 
           AND date >= '2014-06-13 14:17:22' 
ORDER  BY -date 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

Is there any mistake in the query?

Comment: It makes no difference how many records your queries return. Your `LIMIT` clause restricts the result set to 10 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care with the [order of precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) with `AND` & `OR` operators (`AND` is evaluated before `OR`). To fix this, you enclose your operations in parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contentmsg 
WHERE  apmc_id = '5284a327e4b0bc1eaf3d118e' 
       AND ( commodity_id IN ( '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33bc', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b6', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33d9', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca3408',
                               '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33e1', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33ec', '5226d086e4b05917e5ca33b4' )
             AND lang_id = '51fb5a2ee4b0e18f7f89ecc8' ) 
        OR ( commodity_id IS NULL 
             AND lang_id IS NULL ) 
           AND date < '2014-07-05 09:25' 
           AND date >= '2014-06-13 14:17:22' 
ORDER  BY -date
```

Comment: I don't suppose that `LIMIT 0,10` has anything to do with it.

Comment: Wow.. Done. :) I'm really sorry. The output is correct but the two records are after the date.. so in the output it will not come.. Thanks a ton pal :)

Comment: Personally I'd throw another set of parens in there and change up the indentation just for clarity, so the entire commodity_id/lang_id concept is in its own little group and it's painfully obvious what the ands and ors are all about.

Comment: @JoeEnos.. Thanks for the Info. can you send me the snippet how you would like to do? So that it would be useful for me?

Comment: @NizamAli I don't want to edit the question or answer with how I'd format it, but basically what I'm saying is mixing and matching and's and or's just makes you think about order of operations. If your WHERE clause contains only ANDs or only ORs, then it's much easier to read (IMO of course). So this would be `WHERE apmc_id = 'x' AND ( (commodity_id in () AND lang_id = 'x') OR (commodity_id is null AND lang_id is null) ) AND date < 'x' AND date >= x`. Those outer parens would line up vertically and represent a single condition, and that way your WHERE clause contains only ANDs.